# PHPMyAdmin Style Error

Tags: php, css, phpmyadmin, styling

I don't know if it's just my computer, but I have been getting this problem recently.
[image: error]

If anybody knows how to fix this, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: I think it is impossible to reproduce. What about a reinstall?

Comment: @davidkonrad can't reinstall; it's on a webhost. I don't have root access.

Comment: Try a different browser or contact your host. Not much you can do here with your limited access permissions

Comment: @Layne Seems to be a chrome error. Got any idea of how to fix such thing?

Comment: Create a read only account and let a friend check it with his chrome version. Maybe yours is corrupted. If so re-install it, if not I wouldn't waste much time and simply use a different browser for this. It's not like you'll spend multiple hours in phpMyAdmin. Would it really be worth your time to find a solution for this instead of simply using a different browser for phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Layne I'd rather find a solution. Since my site is in BETA, I spend many hours working with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce; what Chrome and phpMyAdmin versions do you have? (The phpMyAdmin version is visible on the main page, and sometimes in the browser title bar).